# Why can't I double-quote a variable with several parameters in it?

Tags: bash, shell, whitespace, expansion, quoting

I'm writing a bash script that uses `rsync` to synchronize directories. According to the [Google shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml):

> - Always quote strings containing variables, command substitutions, spaces or shell meta characters, unless careful unquoted expansion is required.
> - Use `"$@"` unless you have a specific reason to use `$*`.

I wrote the following test case scenario:

```
#!/bin/bash

__test1(){
  echo stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 $@
  stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 $@
}

__test2(){
  echo stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 "$@"
  stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 "$@"
}


PARAM+=" --dry-run "
PARAM+=" mirror.leaseweb.net::archlinux/"
PARAM+=" /tmp/test"


echo "test A: ok"
__test1 nice -n 19 rsync $PARAM 

echo "test B: ok"
__test2 nice -n 19 rsync $PARAM

echo "test C: ok"
__test1 nice -n 19 rsync "$PARAM"

echo "test D: fails"
__test2 nice -n 19 rsync "$PARAM"
```

(I need `stdbuf` to immediately observe output in my longer script that i'm running)

So, my question is: why does test D fail with the below message?

```
rsync: getaddrinfo:  --dry-run  mirror.leaseweb.net 873: Name or service not known
```

The `echo` in every test looks the same. If I'm suppose to quote all variables, why does it fail in this specific scenario?

Comment: FYI -- all-caps variable names are [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) for variables with meaning to the OS or system, whereas names with lower-case characters are reserved for application use. By using lower-case names, you avoid overwriting variables with meaning to the system by mistake (keep in mind that setting a regular shell variable will automatically overwrite any like-named environment variable).

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!") is also directly on-point; it shows some of the cases where the unquoted version won't work (and you *have* to use either an array, a function, or another alternative).

Comment: Charles Duffy, thank you. I've renamed all variables to lower case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Fred — using arrays is best.  Here's a bit of explanation, and some debugging tips.

Before running the tests, I added

```
echo "$PARAM"
set|grep '^PARAM='
```

to actually show what `PARAM` is.`**`  In your original test, it is:

```
PARAM=' --dry-run  mirror.leaseweb.net::archlinux/ /tmp/test'
```

That is, it is a single string that contains multiple space-separated pieces.

As a rule of thumb (with exceptions!`*`), bash will split words unless you tell it not to.  In tests A and C, the unquoted `$@` in `__test1` gives bash an opportunity to split `$PARAM`.  In test B, the unquoted `$PARAM` in the call to __test2`has the same effect.  Therefore,`rsync` sees each space-separated item as a separate parameter in tests A-C.

In test D, the `"$PARAM"` passed to `__test2` is not split when `__test2` is called, because of the quotes.  Therefore, `__test2` sees only one parameter in `$@`.  Then, inside `__test2`, the quoted `"$@"` keeps that parameter together, so it is not split at the spaces.  As a result, `rsync` thinks the entirety of `PARAM` is the hostname, so fails.

If you use Fred's solution, the output from `sed|grep '^PARAM='` is

```
PARAM=([0]="--dry-run" [1]="mirror.leaseweb.net::archlinux/" [2]="/tmp/test")
```

That is bash's internal notation for an array: `PARAM[0]` is `"--dry-run"`, etc.  You can see each word individually.  `echo $PARAM` is not very helpful for an array, since it only outputs the first word (here, `--dry-run`).

### Edits

`*` As Fred points out, one exception is that, in the assignment `A=$B`, `B` will not be expanded.  That is, `A=$B` and `A="$B"` are the same.

`**` As ghoti points out, instead of `set|grep '^PARAM='`, you can use `declare -p PARAM`.  The [declare builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#options) with the `-p` switch will print out a line that you could paste back into the shell to recreate the variable.  In this case, that output is:

```
declare -a PARAM='([0]="--dry-run" [1]="mirror.leaseweb.net::archlinux/" [2]="/tmp/test")'
```

This is a good option.  I personally prefer the `set|grep` approach because `declare -p` gives you an extra level of quoting, but both work fine.  **Edit** As @rici points out, use `declare -p` if an element of your array might include a newline.

As an example of the extra quoting, consider `unset PARAM ; declare -a PARAM ; PARAM+=("Jim's")` (a new array with one element).  Then you get:

```
set|grep:   PARAM=([0]="Jim's")
      # just an apostrophe ^
declare -p: declare -a PARAM='([0]="Jim'\''s")'
      #    a bit uglier, in my opinion ^^^^
```

Comment: @C34654 Glad to hear it, and welcome to the site!  Please upvote answers that are helpful to you, and accept the answer that you think best solved your problem, so the system (and future readers) will know your question has been answered.  Happy hacking!

Comment: Quick note : you write "As a rule of thumb (with exceptions!), bash will split words unless you tell it not to.".  One big exception is variable assignment.  For instance, for Bash, `A=$B` works just as well as `A="$B"`, even if variable `B` contains spaces.  Similarly, `A=$B$C` does not require quotes.  But if you want to add a space between the two, then quotes are needed (e.g. `A=$B $C`).  Same thing applies to other types of expansions used in assignments.  But in a command, double quotes are needed more often than not.

Comment: @cxw, great answer and debug explanation. One thing I'll add is that you may get a better idea of what's inside the variable by using `declare -p PARAM` instead of your `set|grep` line.

Comment: @cxw: if you're going to use `set|grep`, include the `=` to avoid showing `PARAM1` and friends. But `declare -p` is better, imho, since it doesn't rely on the value being a single line. (Try an array containing a value containing a newline.)

Answer (score 4):

It fails because `"$PARAM"` expands as a single string, and no word splitting is performed, although it contains what should be interpreted by the command as several arguments.

One very useful technique is to use an array instead of a string.  Build the array like this :

```
declare -a PARAM
PARAM+=(--dry-run)
PARAM+=(mirror.leaseweb.net::archlinux/)
PARAM+=(/tmp/test)
```

Then, use an array expansion to perform your call :

```
__test2 nice -n 19 rsync "${PARAM[@]}"
```

The `"${PARAM[@]}"` expansion has the same property as the `"$@"` expansion : it expands to a list of items (one word per item in the array/argument list), no word splitting occurs, just as if each item was quoted.

Comment: in that case shouldn't test B also fail?

Comment: No, because in test B `$PARAM` is unquoted, and word splitting occurs before the call to the test function is made.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it

Comment: Please note that relying on word splitting performed on an unquoted variable expansion requires you to be 100% sure there is no extra whitespace inside that will cause what should be understood as a single argument to be actually split in two.  If such a thing may happen, then you need to put quotes inside, and it gets ugly.  You avoid all of that with the array-based solution above.